signtool.exe hangs on "Submitting digest for signing..." when running in Azure devops
Using signtool.exe with an "Azure Trusted Signing Account" in Azure devops scripts, the process hangs at:

Submitting digest for signing...

This is the PowerShell script block we use at Azure devops, which is based on the docs from Azure Trusted Signing Account:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Preparing Windows EXE signing tools
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/windows-signing-tool
        script: |
          Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -OutFile .\nuget.exe
          .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools -Version 10.0.22621.3233 -x
          .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client -Version 1.0.53 -x
          ./"Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib "Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\bin\x86\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf ".\signing-metadata.json" "<obscurecFolder>/MyProject.exe"

The log output:
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\c16ea5da-1997-4e32-9ef5-9e9268766943.ps1'"
DEBUG:    5+  >>>> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -OutFile 
.\nuget.exe
DEBUG:    6+  >>>> .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools -Version 10.0.22621.3233 -x
Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\



Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233' with respect to project '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 751 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233'
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.3233' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools/10.0.22621.3233/microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools.10.0.22621.3233.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools/10.0.22621.3233/microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools.10.0.22621.3233.nupkg 7ms
Installed Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.3233 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools\10.0.22621.3233 with content hash v67zwCb9JOpfPxdSroZukIKHruU6FUB+KwcmSPcVvUFyYtcyvcUign5y8jPQNi54CVzWvaTg646e62LbanUkxg==.
Adding package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233' to folder '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool'
Added package 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools.10.0.22621.3233' to folder '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.3233' to <obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool
Executing nuget actions took 5.09 sec
DEBUG:    7+  >>>> .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client -Version 1.0.53 -x
Feeds used:
  C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\



Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53' with respect to project '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool', targeting 'Any,Version=v0.0'
Gathering dependency information took 1.09 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53'
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client 1.0.53' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.trusted.signing.client/1.0.53/microsoft.trusted.signing.client.1.0.53.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.trusted.signing.client/1.0.53/microsoft.trusted.signing.client.1.0.53.nupkg 9ms
Installed Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client 1.0.53 from https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.trusted.signing.client\1.0.53 with content hash lou6NowgbY3S/Yn0+WSeI+Dl8SCmvmqkeAzt2Pgs51QL5/kHh+w8FJgutYGM+j2TB11a9zNc0EBWjOGWdwWtoQ==.
Adding package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53' to folder '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool'
Added package 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client.1.0.53' to folder '<obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client 1.0.53' to <obscurecFolder>\windows-signing-tool
Executing nuget actions took 1.45 sec

These mean the first three commands worked fine...
after that we have:
./"Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib "Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\bin\x86\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf ".\signing-metadata.json" "<obscurecFolder>/MyProject.exe"

Trusted Signing

Version: 1.0.53

"Metadata": {
  "Endpoint": "https://eus.codesigning.azure.net",
  "CodeSigningAccountName": "ObscuredTrustedSignAccName",
  "CertificateProfileName": "ObscuredTrustedSignAccCertificateProfileName",
  "ExcludeCredentials": []
}

Submitting digest for signing...

When executed locally, the output of the same last command is:
Trusted Signing

Version: 1.0.60

"Metadata": {
  "Endpoint": "https://eus.codesigning.azure.net",
  "CodeSigningAccountName": "ObscuredTrustedSignAccName",
  "CertificateProfileName": "ObscuredTrustedSignAccCertificateProfileName",
  "ExcludeCredentials": []
}

Submitting digest for signing...

OperationId 12121212-acbc-acbc-acbc-49603042d34c: InProgress

Signing completed with status 'Succeeded' in 20.5563194s

Successfully signed: <obscurecFolder>/MyProject.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0

Why can signtool.exe not continue when ran by devops, but works fine in my local environment??

The solution was to make azure devops connect its azure cli to the required subscription and grating permissions to its credentials prior to executing signtool.exe. By trial and error it seems the missing permissions/azure cli connection was causing a silent error on the pipelines...
This is how I resoulved it:

Create a "Service connections" from your "Project Settings" in Azure devops;
grab the "Display Name" from the  "Manage Service Principal" of the created "Service connection" (it will be found at the "Manage Service Principal" overview page );
navigate the "Trusted Signing Account" and click the tab "Access control (IAM)";
add the role "Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer" to the service principal found when search by the "Display Name" from step 2;

That takes care of permissions... now back to the configuration of the pipeline:
After that, I moved the execution of "signtool" to the "AzureCLI@2" task and all started working:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Preparing Windows EXE signing tools
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/windows-signing-tool
        script: |
          Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe -OutFile .\nuget.exe
          .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools -Version 10.0.26100.1 -x
          .\nuget.exe install Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client -Version 1.0.60 -x

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Login Azure cli and Sign Windows EXE using Azure Trusted Signing Account
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: <Obscured name of my "Service connection">
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/windows-signing-tool
        addSpnToEnvironment: true
        inlineScript: |
          Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
          ./"Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools\bin\10.0.26100.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib "Microsoft.Trusted.Signing.Client\bin\x86\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf ".\signing-metadata.json" "<obscurecFolder>/MyProject.exe"


Hopefully this helps someone else
